# How to merge all models in laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show all slideshow when the images are not blank.

```
public function index()
{

    $sliderProducts = Product::query()->select('slider')->whereNotNull('slider');
    $sliderServices = Service::query()->select('slider')->whereNotNull('slider');
    $slideShows = $sliderProducts->merge($sliderServices)
        ->union($sliderProducts)
        ->union($sliderServices)
        ->get();
    return view('Home.index', compact('slideShows'));
}
```

Comment: You just need $slideShows = $sliderProducts->merge($sliderServices); That should be it

Comment: I see this error .  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::merge()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$sliderProducts = Product::query()->select('slider')->whereNotNull('slider');
$sliderServices = Service::query()->select('slider')->whereNotNull('slider');
```

**$sliderProducts** and **$sliderServices** will both be instances of **Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder** class

You need to fetch the collection before trying to merge them

To get the collection you can use **get()** on the Builder. Try

```php
public function index()
{

    $sliderProducts = Product::query()->select('slider')->whereNotNull('slider')->get();
    $sliderServices = Service::query()->select('slider')->whereNotNull('slider')->get();

    $slideShows = $sliderProducts->concat($sliderServices);

    return view('Home.index', compact('slideShows'));
}
```

Or to execute a union query you can do

```php
public function index()
{

    $sliderProducts = Product::query()->select('slider')->whereNotNull('slider');
    $sliderServices = Service::query()->select('slider')->whereNotNull('slider');

    $slideShows = $sliderProducts
        ->union($sliderServices)
        ->get();

    return view('Home.index', compact('slideShows'));
}
```